# Stream processing that requires previous events for computations

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a problematic use-case when processing events from production: I need to create time sections when a given task has been acitvely processed. As some start and stop events may arrive to kafka after a longer time I need to recalculate the whole history and have access to all previous events of the given task. As task are short lived I am using kafka streams aggregation to hold for each task the list of previous events and with each new event I recalculate all time sections.

However with new requirement to have the same functionality for machines and people the same solution breaks because holding all the past events in the aggregate grows with time and finally surpass kafka message size limit.

What options do I have to deal with such problem in Kafka ecosystem? Or maybe there are some better alternatives outside Kafka I should consider?

Comment: I didn't think Session Windows were bounded in terms of Kafka record size, but as I commented to you last month, yes an external database is common, but it is not provided out of the box with Kafka Streams... Nor do I think this is really a Kafka question. You can run into the same issues with Flink, Spark, etc.

Comment: Use a transform to write the state changes to a database. Instead of adding them to one huge say collection/table, write them out as individual payloads. After you receive the sentinel in the event feed, use that to kick off another task/function/batchprocess to grab all the records and dump them on a topic. If you need to keep track of the window that was just processed, write out the time window that you processed and save it to a topic/state store or database for later. Make another stream processor to aggregate the data then write your final aggregation out to another topic.